# How to query tuples of columns in Django database queries?

Tags: django, postgresql, tuples, aggregate-functions

I have some table `ports(switch_ip, slot_number, port_number, many, more, columns)` and would like to achieve the following PostgreSQL query using Django:

```
SELECT switch_ip, array_agg((slot_number, port_number, many, more, columns) ORDER BY slot_number, port_number) info
FROM ports
GROUP BY switch_ip
ORDER BY switch_ip
```

Using [`django.contrib.postgres.aggregates`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/) here's what I got so far:

```
Port.objects \
    .values('switch_ip') \
    .annotate(
        info=ArrayAgg('slot_number', ordering=('slot_number', 'port_number'))
    ) \
    .order_by('switch_ip')
```

I am unable to include more than one column in the `ArrayAgg`. None of `ArrayAgg(a, b, c)`, `ArrayAgg((a, b, c))`, `ArrayAgg([a, b, c])` seem to work. A workaround could involve separate `ArrayAgg`s for each column and each with the same ordering. I would despise this because I have many columns. Is there any nicer workaround, possibly more low-level?

I suspect this is no issue with ArrayAgg itself but rather with tuple expressions in general. Is there any way to have tuples at all in Django queries? For example, what would be the corresponding Django of:

```
SELECT switch_ip, (slot_number, port_number, many, more, columns) info
FROM ports
```

If this is not yet possible in Django, how feasible would it be to implement?

Comment: Just to understand your problem, why do you want these values to be returned in a tuple, instead of just building the tuple in python?

Comment: @GrandPhuba To solve my original problem: Not having to annotate with multiple `info1=ArrayAgg(a, ordering=o), info2=ArrayAgg(b, ordering=o), info3=ArrayAgg(c, ordering=o)` where `o` is the same ordering every time. If `ArrayAgg` could work on tuples it would simply be something like `info=ArrayAgg((a, b, c), ordering=o)`. Because I suspect this is no problem specific to `ArrayAgg` I broadened my question to tuples in Django in general.

Answer (score 3):

I have spent lot of time searching for a working solution and here is a full recipe with code example.

1. You need to define **Array** "function" with square brackets in template

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Func

class Array(Func):
    template = '%(function)s[%(expressions)s]'
    function = 'ARRAY'
```

2. You need to define output field format (it must be array of some django field). For example an array of strings

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models.fields import CharField

out_format = ArrayField(CharField(max_length=200))
```

3. Finally make an ArrayAgg expression

```
from django.db.models import F

annotate = {'2-fields': ArrayAgg(Array(F('field1'), F('field2'), output_field=out_format), distinct=True) }
model.objects.all().annotate(**annotate)
```

4. (Optional) If field1 or field2 are not CharFields, you may include Cast as an argument of Array

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


annotate = {'2-fields': ArrayAgg(Array(Cast(F('field1'), output_field=CharField(max_length=200)), F('field2'), output_field=out_format), distinct=True) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having done a bit more research I guess one could add the missing tuple functionality as follows:

1. Create a new model field type named `TupleField`. The implementation might look kind of similar to [`django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield). `TupleField` would be rather awkward because I don't think any RDBMS allows for composite types to be used as column types so usage of `TupleField` would be limited to (possibly intermediate?) query results.
2. Create a new subclass of `django.db.models.Expression` which wraps multiple expressions on its own (like `Func` in general, so looking at `Func`'s implementation might be worthwile) and evaluates to a `TupleField`. Name this subclass `TupleExpression` for example.

Then I could simply annotate with `ArrayAgg(TupleExpression('slot_number', 'port_number', 'many', 'more', 'columns'), ordering=('slot_number', 'port_number'))` to solve my original problem. This would annotate each `switch_ip` with correctly-ordered arrays of tuples where each tuple represents one switch port.

Comment: Downvoting this because adopting any NoSQL database is likely to be more productive and fulfilling than wrestling with Django internals to achieve something as basic as a tuple. Oh wait I can't. Why is the downward arrow shown then?